# Pundit - rails authorization: one policy for all models

Tags: pundit

I have large number of models and I need one policy (applicationPolicy) to handle their common actions.
Do I need to create a policy class for each model?

Comment: I meant : I  have large number of Controllers...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make `Common Policy` for all your controllers in your `application_policy.rb`.

But for better control, use separate `policies` for each controller.

Refer [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/straightforward-rails-authorization-with-pundit/)

Comment: Thanks Chetan, I did it like what you suggested and works fine.